# How to get all positions of the set bits in bitmaps of Redis?

Tags: redis

As I know we can get/set an individual bit and count it but there is not command to retrieve all positions of the set bits.

My solution was iterate over all the possible index and ask if it is or not set. 
Disadvantage of this way is that it lead to a huge amount of getbits requests if the key contain large amount of bits, ex: 1,000,000 bits. And I need to know beforehand which indexes I have to get.

Other solution is using 'get' command to get value of the key then scan it on client side. But I am looking for a better solution it can take advantage of redis in handle bitmaps

Anyone know about better solution? I would really appreciate any comment.

Comment: I can think of a mixture between the two: use GETRANGE or BITFIELD to get just a specific range, say 32 bits at a time, then calculate that client side. Then maybe use a Lua script to save roundtrips.

The fastest approach would be to use a C module that calcualtes that directly in memory. But it's harder to maintain of course.

Comment: "Better" is problematic - if your on bits are a many, returning their indices may cost more (traffic-wise) than just GETting the binary string itself. Anyway, what @Not_a_Golfer said.

Answer (score 0):

You can iteratively call the [`BITPOS` command](https://redis.io/commands/bitpos) to find the offsets of 1-bits, changing the start location each time.

If your application is sensitive to dense fields, you can take a divide-and-conquer approach by doing a [BITCOUNT](https://redis.io/commands/bitcount) on start-end segements to find the high-impact regions in your bitmap.