# How to determine all of the set bits in a Redis bitfield?

Tags: php, redis, bit-fields

I need the ability to identify the index of each set bit (value=1) in a Redis bitfield. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52639300/how-to-get-all-positions-of-the-set-bits-in-bitmaps-of-redis) which suggests using the `bitpos` function but there's a problem. As far as I can tell it takes the start of the range with a byte level specificity so if there's multiple set bits in a given byte I can only see the first set bit within that byte. Alternatively I could grab the entire value but I'm getting incorrect answers when I do this (my code is in PHP).

```
    $temp = $redis_conn->getRange('mykey', 0, -1);
    $output = "";
    for($i=0;$i < strlen($temp); $i++) {
        $up = unpack('H*', $temp[$i]);
        $bc = base_convert($up[1], 16, 2);
        if($bc == '0') {
            $bc = '00000000';
        }
        $output .= $bc;
    }
    
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($output); $i++) {
        if($output[$i] == '1') {
            echo ($i+1).PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
```

I think this code should work but the answers are wildly incorrect. I put a check in for a one character string because when all 8 digits should've been 0 the base_convert only gave me one digit back throwing the indices way off. Looking through I can see that there are other places where the result of `base_convert` is not 8 digits which can account for a lot of the mismatch between expected and actual results but not all of it. Does anyone know of a good way to get either of these methods to work? Either the `bitpos` command or converting the binary after pulling down the entire bitfield?

EDIT: As an example I told it to set the bits at indices 12921, 72312 and 74616. I have 12921 coming out as expected but the highest index I'm seeing is 73623.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the values in `$temp` and where the code gives an incorrect value.

Comment: As a guess - it may be that you are always expecting 8 digit numbers in `$bc`, if so you can left pad it with 0's using `str_pad($bc, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)`.

Comment: @NigelRen Is there a reason why base_convert would output less than 8 characters? Shouldn't every symbol be represented by 8 bits? Also, how do I know that I need to pad on the left as opposed to the right?

Comment: Converting 4 to binary is 100 - the leading 0's are not significant for numbers - but may be significant if you are expecting things to be byte aligned.  You left pad as 100 as 8 bit should be 00000100.

Comment: @NigelRen Ok, the left padding worked for me. If you put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are always expecting it to produce 8 characters from `base_convert()`, but it will only provide enough digits to represent the number.

You can pad the number with leading 0's to make sure it's always 8 chars using `str_pad()` and `STR_PAD_LEFT` to left pad the string...

```
$output .= str_pad($bc, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```